# Helper for TWinControl

Tags: delphi

I like to "override" the TWinControl.CNKeyDown, to use the Enter key as Tab, without modifying original VCL sources.
I do the same, with SetFocus, witch works well.

The helper type declared as:

```
type
   TWinControlEx = class helper for TWinControl
   private
       procedure SetFocus; reintroduce;
       procedure CNKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); reintroduce;
   end;
```

The overrided method looks like:

```
if (Message.CharCode = 13) and (Pos('Cr_To_Tab',ImeName)>0) and (Pos('No_Cr_To_Tab',ImeName)=0) then
      begin
        if not ((GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) and not $7FFF) <> 0) then
        begin
          Message.CharCode := 9;
        end;
      end;
   Message.CharCode := 9;
   inherited;
```

But it seems that when my code runs, it still use the original version. The other frustrating thing, is that I can't debug the problem, because, when I put a breakpoint inside the CNKeyDown method, it never stops, and the IDE (RAD Studio 10.2) puts a cross inside it.

Can someone give me some instruction?

Comment: Your class needs to inherit from TWinControl and to override it with the behavior you want. Concerning the debugging breakpoints, you need to enable debug dcu's for your project - see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Compiling at Debugging section

Comment: It only works, when use helper, if I declare the class like TWinControlEx = class(TWinControl), than nothing happens, and the function newer called.I also have enabled debug dcus, but still cant debug

Comment: This is all wrong. Subclass via the WindowProc property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant use a class helper to reintroduce new versions of existing methods like you are attempting to.

A class helper is not the solution.  You need to instead either:

1. Derive a new class from the desired original class, like `TEdit`, and `override` its applicable `virtual`/`dynamic` methods, like `WndProc()`, `KeyDown()`, etc, and then create instances of your custom class at run-time instead of the original class.  You can either install your custom class in the IDE at design-time, or you can implement your class as an Interposer so it overrides the original class only at run-time.  See [Two Approaches to Sub-classing Components Compared](http://caryjensen.blogspot.com/2014/01/two-approaches-to-sub-classing.html) for more details.
2. Don't derive a new class at all. Simply subclass the `WindowProc` property of the desired object instanc(es) of the original class at run-time. Then you can handle their window messages before they do.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you don't have to modify VCL sources to extend descendants of `TWinControl` as it has a whole bunch of `virtual` methods that can be extended in descendant classes using the `override` keyword.
`SetFocus` is such a virtual method.

I wonder, whether you really need to reimplement `TWinControl.CNKeyDown`. Can't you just override `TWinControl.KeyDown`?

It happens to be that `TWinControl.KeyDown` is a virtual method, too.
Actually, `TWinControl.KeyDown` is declared `dynamic` but that's a trivial matter here, as `dynamic` methods are [semantically equivalent](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Methods#Virtual_and_Dynamic_Methods) and can be overridden as "normal" `virtual` declared methods.

The keyword `reintroduce` is only used when a virtual method is hidden in a descendant class by declaring a method with the same name. The compiler emits a warning then, which can be avoided by using the `reintroduce` keyword.

Your class should look something like the following:

#### interface

```
TWinControlEx = class(TWinControl)
protected
  procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
public
  procedure SetFocus; override;
end;
```

#### implementation

```
procedure TWinControlEx.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if (Key = VK_RETURN) and not (ssCtrl in Shift) then
    Key := VK_TAB;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TWinControlEx.SetFocus;
begin
  // do something and/or call
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thank's for your comment, but unfortunately the method works only (the setfocus, keydown still not), when I declare twincownrolex as helper. If it simply derived from twincontrol, nothing happens.

Comment: @NemoPeti Are you sure, you used the `override` keyword in your derived class? If you (falsely) used `reintroduced` like in your question, it won't work expectably.

Comment: @NemoPeti Furthermore, have you read the documentation chapter that my answer links to? I highly recommend to do so in order to understand how virtual methods are used (in Delphi).